# While trying to read a multipart/signed mail, the original attachments are ignored and only smime.7ps file is displayed

Tags: jakarta-mail, content-type, multipart

I am trying to connect to a mailbox and read the messages and attachments. Here when there is any mail with a digital signature, only the smime.7ps file is read and others(xml,pdf etc.,) are ignored. I could observe that in such mails only the signature part of mail is read and body part is ignored. I am using Multipart here. Please let me know if there is any different way of handling which could help me to get the body part attachments read for mails with Digital Signature?                                                                   Here is the part of my code which fetches the messages/attachments:

```
    if (contentType.contains("multipart")){
            Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
            int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
            for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                    // this part is attachment
                    String fileName = part.getFileName();

                    attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
                    part.saveFile(SaveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);


                } else {
                    // this part may be the message content
                    messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
                }
            }

            if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
                attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
            }
            //}
        } else if (contentType.contains("text/plain") || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
            Object content = message.getContent();
            if (content != null) {
                messageContent = content.toString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: We need to see how you're doing it to tell you what you might be doing wrong.  Can you post your code?  Are you handling the nested multiparts that occur with digitally signed messages?

Comment: Thanks Shannon! I have included the part of code in the description.

Comment: In output, for normal mails, all attachments are retrieved (Any number), but for the mails with digital signature, only smime.p7s is retrieved and others are ignored. Generally with multipart all parts of the mail should be read. Can you please clarify and help to solve this.

Comment: Your code assumes only a single level of nesting for multiparts.  A signed message may have an inner multipart containing the attachments nested in an outer multipart with the signature.  See the [msgshow.java](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java) sample program for an example of how to recursively handle nested multiparts.

Comment: Thanks much for the clarification Shannon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Shannon! Your input of nested multiparts actually helped me to solve the issue!

MimeMultipart multiPart = (MimeMultipart) message.getContent(); //*** Reading the Email Message & its contents***

```
//***Your code for Different actions with Email Message
int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {

    //***Reading Body Part contents from the Email Message
    MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
        //***Your Code for Different actions with Body part contents

        //***Now the below step would help you to check if the above retrieved content(part) is having any further multiparts nested in it. 
        //***Once the check is true, then you can instantiate that content again as a multipart and retrieve the related details.
        if(part.getContent() instanceof Multipart){ 
            Multipart multipart = (Multipart) part.getContent();
            for (int j = 0; j < multipart.getCount(); j++) {
                 MimeBodyPart bodyPart = (MimeBodyPart)multipart.getBodyPart(j);
            }
        }
}
```